# Python - Take second member and beyond of a split string

Tags: python

I have a code which counts the vowels from an input (string) - Server/Client

```
data = conn.recv(1024) 
point = data.decode("ASCII")
points=point.split(' ')
MESSAGE = points[0]
```

And then if the client wants to have it's string vowels count, we call it by:

```
if points[0]=="VOWELS":
    nrVowels(points)
```

Let's say I want to count the vowels of 'Hello World'

> VOWELS Hello World

by `nrVowels(points)`, the problem is that it will also count the vowels of the word 'VOWELS'. If I make it `nrVowels(points[1])` it will only take the word 'Hello'.

As you see, I want to ignore the points[0] which is the message itself to idenitfy the action (in this case, 'VOWELS').

Is there a way so I can ignore the first member?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ignore the first element of a list, you can slice it:

```
nrVowels(points[1:])
```